# Elasticsearch index is created but analyzer is not found

Tags: node.js, database, elasticsearch, indexing, nestjs

I have implemented custom analyzer for a text field, but I can not apply it to a field. Index is created successfully and I am able to search indexed documents like text (full words), but I can not use my 'myCharacterAnalyzer' analyzer in the query.

Later I tried to test 'myCharacterAnalyzer' passing the test textual data (see the end of the code sample) but it says that 'myCharacterAnalyzer' is not found. It makes sense, as it is not applied to my index, but **I need to register that analyzer and make it work.**

```
const indexName: string = 'test-index';

const mapping: MappingTypeMapping = {
  properties: {
    id: {
      type: 'keyword',
    },
    testTextualField: {
      type: 'text',
      analyzer: 'myCharacterAnalyzer',
    },
    
  },
};

const settings: IndicesIndexSettings = {
  analysis: {
    analyzer: {
      myCharacterAnalyzer: {
        type: 'custom',
        tokenizer: 'myCharacterTokenizer',
        filter: ['lowercase'],
      },
      autocompleteSearch: {
        type: 'custom',
        tokenizer: 'lowercase',
      },
    },
    tokenizer: {
      myCharacterTokenizer: {
        type: 'ngram',
        min_gram: 1,
        max_gram: 15,
        token_chars: [],
      },
    },
  },
};

await this.esService.indices.create({
  index: indexName,
  mappings: mapping,
  settings: settings,
});


await this.esService.indices.analyze({
  index: indexName,
  analyzer: 'myCharacterAnalyzer',
  text: 'Red brown fox',
});
```

Error I am getting running the last (in the example above) method:

> ResponseError: illegal_argument_exception
> Root causes:
> illegal_argument_exception: failed to find analyzer [myCharacterAnalyzer]